# Angular, datepicker not working on Safari

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, safari

I have alittle problem with datepicker input. I have a piece of code like this, that gets the birth of date when sign-up;

```
        <div>
          <label for="date_of_birth"><b>Your Birthday</b></label>
          <input type="date" placeholder="Please enter your birthday" name="date_of_birth" required 
          [(ngModel)]="register.date_of_birth" style="margin-left: 20px;" date-picker> 
        </div>
```

It works fine with Chrome, when someone clicks on the input place, the date picker automatickly shows up. But at Safari, this is not working. I couldnt figure it out. What do I need to do in order this date picker to also work in Safari?

Comment: Which version for safari?

Comment: You can Angular Bootstrap make sure node module removed and install again with npm i and please nom run build after npm start i hope it work sure.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is expected when you only rely on the browser native functionality, this means each browsers will interpret ht `type="date"` separately, if you need consistent behaviour across browsers you need to use third party library, ie. Angular Material, Angular Bootstrap etc.

Comment: Oh my bad then. Thanks a lot for the answer, I will try ng-bootstrap and give your credits as soon as I can if it works.